# Access user email from Session for a google form submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am a Google scripts newbie. I have a script that runs whenever a form is submitted. However even when I log out and clear my browser cache, the script always records my email. How can I make it record the email of whoever accesses the form?

```
function getUserInfo(){
   var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not possible like that. Use the form native option to include respondents emails and read it as a submitted column.